# navigator.notification.confirm does not work on iphone for Phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova, notifications, plist

I created an Android app with phonegap that calls navigator.notification.confirm.  This works fine for Android.  However, when I bring it over to the Mac and build it in XCode I don't get a pop notification.  From the web searching I have done I see a reference to cordova.plist and/or phonegap.plist.  I do not find either of those files in my project.  I do have a .plist.  I attempted to add:

```
<key>Notification</key>
<string>CDVNotification</string>
```

to the project plist but that does not help.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In xcode cordova.plist is replaced  to  config.xml and there you have to define
 as plugin key and value

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  That and I did not have the correct Cordova.js version.